# UIsplitViewController not RootViewController

Tags: cocoa-touch, uikit, uisplitviewcontroller

I want to show SplitViewController view. But I don't want my SplitViewController as the rootView Controller . I want UInavigationViewController as rootViewController and want to present SplitViewController view after first view. Is this possible ?

Comment: [custom UISplitViewController](http://iphone-dev-tips.alterplay.com/2011/05/custom-uisplitviewcontroller-for-ipad.html). Check it out. Sorry for myself ads.

Answer (score 0):

No.  [Apple Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406355/uisplitviewcontroller-not-rootviewcontroller)  "The split view controller’s view should always be installed as the root view of your application window. You should never present a split view inside of a navigation or tab bar interface."  You might modally display other views over the UISplitViewController to make it appear as if it were not the root controller...

Comment: But what if I remove all subviews of the window and swap in my split view? (It doesn't work either but then it would be root controller). Strange behavior. Any explanation?

Answer (score 0):

My answer in this question may help you,

[remove-split-view-and-show-another-xib-in-the-whole-screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9782968/remove-split-view-and-show-another-xib-in-the-whole-screen/9817560#9817560)

thanks,

Naveen Shan